# startActivity without adding to back stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This question has been asked in different ways before but I have yet to find a solution that is working. I believe the issue to be related to the intent flags for starting an activity but adding all possible solutions the problem still persists. Originally no_histroy and clear_top were sufficient but that no longer works and neither does new_task or clear_task with/out the aforementioned.

In an existing production app the user has a recyclerview of local pdf files. When they tap one in the recyclerview we call method showPdf() see snippet. Stepping back in the stack is working fine (so far). On the same fragment as the recyclerview the user can then download more pdf files. This button moves to another fragment that's a webview. Attached to the WebView is a JS interface class that will handle actions in the WebView of which downloading and showing a pdf is one of them. So the user downloads this pdf and it uses the same method showPdf(). User uses back button which returns to WebView. User presses back again and this should return to the recyclerview fragment but instead it returns to the activity started from the original recyclerview item tap. See the flow in wireframe, follow green -> orange -> red.

```
public void showPdf(Uri path) {
    AppLog.d(TAG, "-> showPdf()");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    if (getContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        displayAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.error_no_pdf_viewer_title),
                getResources().getString(R.string.error_no_pdf_viewer_body),
                null,
                null);
    }
}
```

Wireframe for an example. Red flow should NOT happen, this should return to MainFragment.
[image]

Comment: in `showPdf()` you are launching a PDF viewer. I assume this is NOT your app but whatever the user has installed that can display a PDF. In this case you should not need any flags in the `Intent` other than `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This should ensure that the viewer opens in its own task and not in yours.

Comment: I'm assuming that loading the PDF viewer is causing a resource issue, so Android unloads some of your fragments (it may also kill off your process or some of your activities). When the user returns from the PDF viewer it is possible that the fragments are gone and need to be reinitialized. It is possible that your code does not anticipate this situation and behaves badly. Please add some logging to the fragment lifecycle methods so you can see if this is what is happening.

Comment: @DavidWasser i just found the root of the problem. I am still getting used to LiveData. The MainFragment was calling the method on a MutableLiveData object from MainViewModel. I updated this to a SingleLiveEvent instead and when returning to MainFragment as the observer saw an updated which fired the Intent.

This problem just goes to show we need better Task and stack views when debugging in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

These Intent flags are still valid ways of removing the Activity from the stack or starting a new Task and getting rid of that task when popping the stack.

The problem was related to MutableLiveData calling showPdf() method from the MainFragment. The observer saw an update when the fragment popped and fired the showPdf() again. Changing this to a SingleLiveEvent resolved the issue and the Activity is no longer in the stack.